# Save a "pretty" JSON Object to disc with json.dump in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I try to save a "pretty" json object which I created from a pandas dataframe.

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/seankross/a412dfbd88b3db70b74b/raw/5f23f993cd87c283ce766e7ac6b329ee7cc2e1d1/mtcars.csv")

import json
d = df.to_dict(orient='records')
j = json.dumps(d, indent=2)
print(j)
```

The printed output looks great and when I copy it to an editor, it seems to work.

```
[
  {
    "model": "Mazda RX4",
    "mpg": 21.0,
    "cyl": 6,
    "disp": 160.0,
    "hp": 110,
    "drat": 3.9,
    "wt": 2.62,
    "qsec": 16.46,
    "vs": 0,
    "am": 1,
    "gear": 4,
    "carb": 4
  }
]
```

However, when I save it to disc, I does not look like expected.

```
with open("beispiel.json", "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(j, write_file)
```

Everything is in one line and is not formatted at all:

```
"[\n  {\n    \"model\": \"Mazda RX4\",\n    \"mpg\": 21.0,\n    \"cyl\": 6,\n    \"disp\": 160.0,\n
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're *double dumping* your data. You just want `json.dump(d, write_file, indent=2)`.

Comment: In fact, you should probably forego `to_dict` with a separate `json.dump` altogether and go directly for https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that *j* is a string, so when you do:

```
with open("beispiel.json", "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(j, write_file)
```

you are writing the string to the file. Just do:

```
json.dump(d, write_file, indent=2)
```

Comment: thank you, totally missed the point what `dump` does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/seankross/a412dfbd88b3db70b74b/raw/5f23f993cd87c283ce766e7ac6b329ee7cc2e1d1/mtcars.csv")

d = df.to_dict(orient='records')

# 1st form
with open("beispiel.json", "w") as write_file:
    write_file.write(json.dumps(d, indent=2))

# or 2nd form
with open("beispiel.json", "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(d, write_file, indent=2)
```

Comment: That's rather inefficient if you don't particularly need `j` as a string later.